# Set Theory : $(P \cup Q)' \cup (P'\cap Q)$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

$$(P \cup Q)' \cup (P'\cap Q) = \  ?$$

**'** = complement.

$P$ and $Q$ are two distinct non empty sets.

I got answer $P'$ . Is it correct?

Comment: You professor will always care far more about the work and process you went through to get to your answer rather than the actual answer. ... can you please show your work?

Comment: Yes it is correct.

Comment: Do you know of [DeMorgan's Laws](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws)? If you use that here you might see something...

Answer (score 1):

Like said if you know DeMorgan's Law you can rewrite 
$(P \cup Q)^\complement=P^\complement \cap Q^\complement$.

Understand that $P^\complement=(P^\complement \cap Q)\cup(P^\complement \cap Q^\complement)$ and you get your answer. You would ofcourse need an elementary set $X$ with $P,Q \in X$ which should be written somewhere in the task..